# How set scrolling for inner recyclerview and stop scrolling outer recyclerview until inner items has reached of top screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have outer Recyclerview1 and each item also have inner Recyclerview2 with many items, and I want when scrolling inner list2 - my parent item need stay in top of screen, until next item of outer list reach to top of screen. Welcome any decisions

Comment: Is both of them in a same direction? I mean vertically.

Comment: yes, both vertically